# SSRS Pull Image variable from file

Tags: c, vb.net, image, reporting-services

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 to create a report and I have an image control that I want to link to a dynamic file name that comes from my database. Unfortunately, they need to be changed before I display the image so I am working with trying to pull it into an Image variable and making changes to it. 
I am experimenting with using Custom Code to do the job but I am failing miserably. I am trying to read the image into a Image variable using System.Drawing.Image.FromFile so I can resize it but I am running into Security issues and Uri issues so I'm not sure this is the correct way to go.

My question is, how do I pull an Image into a SSRS Image variable from an external file so I can change the Image before displaying it?  Is there a reasonable way to do this?

Comment: When the file is added to the location, and the location recorded in the database. Would it be possible at that point to resize the image to suitable size?

Comment: Hey BobF, I'm trying that... I have a new question now  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529229/converting-filestream-to-writeablebitmap-to-jpeg-to-byte-array-for-ssrs